# MySQL:creating cursor dynamically in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-insert

Below i have created one procedure, which took 2 parameter called company_name and SN_F,

I want to pass the **table name** to procedure as parameter for which i want to create cursor.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE transfer_t(IN company_name varchar(50), SN_f int)
BEGIN


DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE dates_f date default null;
DECLARE high_f float default 0.0;
DECLARE low_f float default 0.0;
DECLARE open_f float default 0.0;
DECLARE close_f float default 0.0;
DECLARE volume_f int default 0;
DECLARE adj_close_f float default 0.0;



DECLARE Company_detail cursor for 
    select Date, high, low, open, close, volume, adj_close from company_name;
    Declare CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
    OPEN Company_detail;
    REPEAT
        FETCH company_detail into dates_f, high_f, low_f, open_f, close_f, volume_f, adj_close_f;

        insert into historic_data(sn ,Date ,High ,low ,open ,close , volume , adj_close) values (SN_f,dates_f,high_f,low_f,open_f,close_f, volume_f, adj_close_f);

        until done END REPEAT;
        close company_detail;


END//
DELIMITER ;
```

above procedure gets created successfully, but whenever i called it like,

```
call transfer_t('tcs_temp', 1);
```

it gives the following **error**

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'test_schema.company_name' doesn't exist
```

Please help me solve this...

Comment: Do you have one table per company? All with the same schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking to copy all records from a table name given as parameter to anther, fixed table. I don't see the need for a cursor here. SQL is a set-based language, which is built to natively perform such kind of operation. You would typically use the `insert into ... select ...` syntax.

On the other hand, you need dynamic SQL if you want to use the table name as variable - which your current code is missing.

The following code should do what you want:

```
delimiter //

create procedure transfer_t(in p_company_name varchar(50), p_sn_f int)
begin
    set @p_sn_f = p_sn_f;
    set @sql = concat(
        'insert into historic_data(sn ,Date ,High ,low ,open ,close , volume , adj_close)',
        ' select ?, date, high, low, open, close, volume, adj_close from ', p_company_name
    );

    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt using @p_sn_f;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
end//

delimiter ;
```